# How to calculate Average of n numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 'n' numpy arrays each with shape (128,)
How to get an average numpy array of shape (128,) for the list of numpy arrays.
I have seen the documentation of numpy's average() and mean() which describes that the average is calculated for all the elements in a single numpy array rather than multiple or list of numpy arrays.
Example

```
numpyArrayList = [ar1,ar2,ar3,ar4...arn]
avgNumpyArray = avg(numpyArrayList)
avgNumpyArray.shape
```

should give result as (128,)
and this array should contain the average of all the numpy arrays

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `np.stack(numpyArrayList)` produce a 2d array?  What shape?  Does `np.mean` work on it (with one of the `axis` values)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `np.mean([ar1,ar2,ar3,ar4...arn], axis=0)`.

Comment: That should however be `axis=1`. I deleted my answer as yours is faster and results in a numpy array, whereas mine did not.

Comment: I don't think so, `axis=1` will give an array of shape `(n,)` instead of `(128,)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the following code

```
ar = [ar1,ar2,ar3,...,arn]
r = np.mean(ar)
```

for axis=0 use following

```
r = np.mean(ar, axis=0)
```

for axis=1 use following

```
r = np.mean(ar, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
mean=0
n=len(numpyArrayList)
for i in numpyArrayList:
    mean += i.sum()/(128.*n)
```

Edit: misunderstood the question, sry